# About Java Layout

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, jtextarea

i still learning about java and
i have simple code

```
import javax.swing.*;

Public class Test extends JFrame{
JLabel name = new JLabel("Name");
JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();

Test(){
    this.setSize(435, 400);
    this.setTitle("Test");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLayout(null);
    name.setBounds(10, 10, 50, 20);
    this.add(name);
    ta.setBounds(90, 10, 300, 200); 
    ta.setLineWrap(true);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(ta);
    this.add(scroll);
}

public static void main(String [] args){
    new Test().setVisible(true);
}
}
```

What layout should i choose ? i want the textarea show beside the name label

Comment: What options are you presenting? You should probably look into a `LayoutManager` instead of hardcoding the layout.

Comment: i'm sorry , i just started today ^^ ...

Comment: `setLayout(null);`  Since you just started today, it is a good time to **not** pick up any bad habits.  That is one of the worst.  Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just a Label and a TextArea, just use a simple `GridLayout`

```
Test(){

    setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));   // sets a Grid Layout with 1 row and 2 columns
    add(name);

    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(ta);
    ta.setLineWrap(true);
    add(scroll);


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new Test();
    frame.setSize(435, 400);
    frame.setTitle("Test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: how about the size ? my textarea and label is bigger than i thought

Comment: Change the size of the frame `frame.setSize(x, y)`.  You should go through the Java GUI tutorials if you're new to everything http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html

Comment: The size of a `JTextArea` can be suggested in the number of rows & columns as well as the font size.  Given the `GridLayout` will then size the other component, setting the size of the frame is unnecessary (and sub-optimal).

Comment: And don't forget to `pack()`.